# What Fragments am I hosting and displaying?

Tags: android

Is there a way to know which `Fragment` is currently *displayed* in a given `<fragment>` container of an `Activity` without keeping track of all the changes via the `onAttachFragment` callback?

Is it even possible to know which fragments are displayed when fragment transactions can take place when the user presses the back key? In this latter case, i.e. when a `Fragment` is re-displayed due to a back, the `onAttach` is not called.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the only way to know for sure which fragment is being displayed is to keep track of that carefully yourself.
For example, you could make a variable in your Activity:

```
Fragment mCurrentDisplayedFragment;
```

and then whenever the user requests a different fragment do:

```
mCurrentFragment = (Fragment) userRequestedFragment;
fragmentManager.replace(container, mCurrentFragment, tag);
```

Then, whenever you needed to do things to the currently displayed fragment, you could triage it by try/catching a cast or with instanceof.

You could also handle the back pressed behavior by overriding that method in the activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int stackSize = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); 
    // This counts up from the bottom so the most recent fragment is the biggest number/size
    backFragId = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(stackSize);
    // Get a handle on the fragment that is about to be popped
    mCurrentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(backFragId);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Also, are you sure that onAttach is not called when a fragment is popped off the stack? I seem to remember that it will be, and you can call through the interface created there (if you have one and the activity implements it) to register the fragment as the current fragment in the activity at the time.

But to directly answer your question, there isn't a built in way to just know what fragment is currently displayed (and there could be more than one!). The implementation details of that are up to you. Hopefully I've given you some ideas of how it could be handled though. You might also find [the FragmentManager documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The `onAttach` method is not called, unfortunately, I think because the Fragment popped out of the back stack is already attached. I cannot believe how messy they built the Fragment framework.

Comment: @Antonio Sesto it was pointed out to me that the Fragment's onResume method will be reliably called every time it is shown. That would be an ideal place to put a call to the Activity interface to register the Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Each time when you add/replace fragment to the container, use tag for it:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();       
ft.add(R.id.container, fragment, tag).commit();
```

then you can find out the fragment is current visible or not:

```
Fragment fg = getFragmentManger().findFragmentByTag(tag);
if(fg.isVisible())
    //fg is the current visible fragment
```

Hope this help!